# Number input won't take 0 as a value in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input field of type `number`. However, if I try to input 0, it will just ignore it.
What's going on?

Here is roughly my code:

```
// render part of the component
return {
<div>
  <input
    type='number'
    step='1'
    min='0'
    max='20'
    value={this.state.myTargetsValue}
    // @ts-ignore
    onFocus={(evt) => evt.target.select()} // This selects all text on the first click
    onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(key, 'myTarget', evt.target.value)}
    className='form-control'
  />
</div>
}
```

Note: the handleChange doesn't make a difference, I removed all code from it for the purpose of testing.

Comment: What's this.state.myTargetsValue ?

Comment: It's likely something to do with `value={this.state.myTargetsValue}` overwriting

Comment: where can I see the definition of variable key? and show me the function handleChange

Comment: Why would it be though? Other values work. Is it perhaps that 0 is being seen as falsy?
The default value of the `this.state.myTargetsValue` should be an empty string.

Comment: if you pass `0` directly into value does it work? I mean `... value={0} ...`

Comment: @theJuls Your probably correct. It'd be nice to know what is in `handleChange()`, or show a failing example that works without using `handleChange()`, but in general when only `0` is having trouble, it usually is because it's getting into some trap where it is being judged as falsey. Check out my answer for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever `0` is acting funny, it generally turns out that its falling into a trap of coming up falsey.

In your `handleChange()` function, it's likely you have some code that is trying to do something along these lines:

```
if (newValue) {
  this.setState({ key: newValue });
}
```

The problem with that is `0` going to fail a check like that. Instead, you'll need to explicitly check the values that aren't good:

```
if (![null, '', false].includes(newValue)) { }
```

is one approach. That would check that it isn't one of the other common falsey values. There are other ways, but the basic idea is to make sure it doesn't just default to normal JavaScript behavior.

Comment: That was exactly what was happening! There are a bunch of other complications within the handleChange function but they can now be dealt with.

Comment: @theJuls for this exact reason, I never rely on truthy or falsey anymore. I make a function out of   `![undefined, null, false].includes(arg)`

Comment: I never thought of doing checks that way before this thread. But surely learned my lesson after this one :P

Comment: Nice one. I had a similar issue, it wasn't so much where it was setting the value, but where the value property of the box was set to `currentValue || ''`, which of course wouldn't display anything for 0

Comment: I had a similar situation as TheButterWorm:  `value={ currentValue || ''  }`, so I changed it to  `value={ currentValue ?? ''  }`  and that worked for me

Comment: Yeah. When this was first posted, that wasn't really an option, but now, that'd be my first pick too. `value ?? ''`.

Comment: Yep, `value ?? ''` worked a treat, thanks @NataliaDuran!

Answer (score 1):

In react, you will need a state that controls that input. Make a constructor, and cal

```
this.state={
    input:0
}
```

And your onChange will be something like

```
e => this.setState({input:e.target.value})
```

Comment: They don't have to initialize the state with a default input. It would default to null which would render as blank and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the `value`, you want to set an initial value upon loading your page. To do this use `defaultValue` like so:

```
<input
  type='number'
  step='1'
  min='0'
  max='20'
  defaultValue={course.credits}
  // @ts-ignore
  onFocus={(evt) => evt.target.select()} // This selects all text on the first click
  onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(key, 'myTarget', evt.target.value)}
  className='form-control'
/>
```